# I want to loop this Script (Azure-powershell / Powershell)

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I want a loop that i can specify the number of increments that I want and
i want to increment some parameters by 1 like $ipconfig $Ipconfigname $publicip
and also 10.0.0.25

the result that I want:

```
#####################################
# Create a public IP address 1
$PublicIP1 = New-AzPublicIpAddress `
    -Name "q9r933209h1" `
    -ResourceGroupName $RgName `
    -Location $Location `
    -AllocationMethod dynamic
#Create an IP configuration with a dynamic private IP address and assign the public IP address to it
$IpConfigName1 = "00iifcow5n1"
$IpConfig1 = New-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig `
    -Name $IpConfigName1 `
    -Subnet $Subnet `
    -PrivateIpAddress 10.0.0.25 `
    -PublicIpAddress $PublicIP1

#####################################   
# Create a public IP address 2
$PublicIP2 = New-AzPublicIpAddress `
    -Name "q9r933209h2" `
    -ResourceGroupName $RgName `
    -Location $Location `
    -AllocationMethod dynamic
#Create an IP configuration with a dynamic private IP address and assign the public IP address to it
$IpConfigName2 = "00iifcow5n2"
$IpConfig2 = New-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig `
    -Name $IpConfigName2 `
    -Subnet $Subnet `
    -PrivateIpAddress 10.0.0.26 `
    -PublicIpAddress $PublicIP2

#####################################   
# Create a public IP address 3
$PublicIP3 = New-AzPublicIpAddress `
    -Name "q9r933209h3" `
    -ResourceGroupName $RgName `
    -Location $Location `
    -AllocationMethod dynamic
#Create an IP configuration with a dynamic private IP address and assign the public IP address to it
$IpConfigName3 = "00iifcow5n3"
$IpConfig3 = New-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig `
    -Name $IpConfigName3 `
    -Subnet $Subnet `
    -PrivateIpAddress 10.0.0.27 `
    -PublicIpAddress $PublicIP3
```

i want a loop that create x number of this

```
#####################################
# Create a public IP address 1
$PublicIP1 = New-AzPublicIpAddress `
    -Name "q9r933209h1" `
    -ResourceGroupName $RgName `
    -Location $Location `
    -AllocationMethod dynamic
#Create an IP configuration with a dynamic private IP address and assign the public IP address to it
$IpConfigName1 = "00iifcow5n1"
$IpConfig1 = New-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig `
    -Name $IpConfigName1 `
    -Subnet $Subnet `
    -PrivateIpAddress 10.0.0.25 `
    -PublicIpAddress $PublicIP1
```

end after loop I want to run this command

```
$NIC = New-AzNetworkInterface `
    -Name X `
    -ResourceGroupName $RgName `
    -Location $Location `
    -NetworkSecurityGroupId $NSG.Id `
    -IpConfiguration $IpConfig1, $IpConfig2, $IpConfig3, .....,$IpConfig(x time)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few ways to loop. In this example I used creating an array and piping to a foreach-object. You dont have to use `$($_)` you can use just `$_`, but i added it for readability.

```
$Loop = 3
(1..$Loop) | foreach-object{
    #####################################
    # Create a public IP address 1
    $PublicIP1 = New-AzPublicIpAddress `
    -Name "q9r933209h$($_)" `
    -ResourceGroupName $RgName `
    -Location $Location `
    -AllocationMethod dynamic
    #Create an IP configuration with a dynamic private IP address and assign the public IP address to it
    $IpConfigName1 = "00iifcow5n$($_)"
    $IpConfig1 = New-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig `
        -Name (Get-Variable -Name "IpConfigName$($_)" -ValueOnly) `
        -Subnet $Subnet `
        -PrivateIpAddress "10.0.0.$(25 + ($_ - 1))" `
        -PublicIpAddress (Get-Variable -Name "PublicIP$($_)" -ValueOnly) `
}
```

Comment: i want to change for each one  $PublicIP1 to $PublicIP2 ... and for $ipconfigName1 to ipconfigName2 ... and $ipconfig1 to $ipconfig2 ...

 because I will use in the end this command :

-IpConfiguration $IpConfig1, $IpConfig2, $IpConfig3, .... 

so can you help me with that too ? that 

-ipConfiguration $ipConfig1,......,$ipconfig($loop)

Comment: it does that already. It changes PublicIP1 to 2 and so on....`(Get-Variable -Name "PublicIP$($_)" -ValueOnly)`

Comment: But can you please see the last command that I want to run after loop. -IpConfiguration take all $ipconfig that are created and for example if we have $loop=3 ! $NIC = New-AzNetworkInterface -IpConfiguration $IpConfig1, $IpConfig2, $IpConfig3

Comment: OK so...the error you are showing is there is no variable named `$IpConfigName3` or `$PublicIP3`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$x = 4
$publicIpParams = @{
    ResourceGroupName = $RgName
    Location = $Location
    AllocationMethod = 'Dynamic'
}
$ipConfiguration = 1..$x | ForEach-Object {
    $publicIP = New-AzPublicIpAddress @publicIpParams -Name ("q9r933209h{0}" -f $_)
    $ipcParams = @{
        Name = "00iifcow5n{0}" -f $_
        Subnet = $Subnet
        PrivateIpAddress = '10.0.0.{0}' -f (24 + $_)
        PublicIpAddress = $publicIp
    }
    New-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig @ipcParams
}

$niParams = @{
    Name = 'X'
    ResourceGroupName = $RgName
    Location = $Location
    NetworkSecurtyGroupId = $nsg.Id
    IpConfiguration = $ipConfiguration
}
New-AzNetworkInterface @niParams
```